# VB - Any way to put 'Resources' items in a Resources subfolder?

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET 2010 project that contains a lot of resources (which I added via My Project --> Resources). And they work just fine.

But what I would like to do (if possible) is organize them by putting them in various subfolders.

For example... in the Solution Explorer, I right-click on the 'Resources' folder and choose 'Add new folder' (which adds a subfolder inside the Resources folder). But when I try to drag one of the Resources items into the subfolder, it doesn't work (it throws an error message stating "Resource could not be loaded because the file to which it is linked could not be found").

So... I was wondering if there is any workaround for this? Since I have so many resources in this project, it would really be helpful if I could have about a dozen subfolders INSIDE the Resources folder, and then put my resources items inside those subfolders. FYI... this is strictly for my own organizational needs while coding the project, so I could care less how the resources items and folders are arranged at compile time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in the folders first, then add them as resources. If the files you pick are already in the project's Resources folder, they won't be recopied.